# Not getting result from Cloud Code Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise, parse-cloud-code

I have been working around this for a really long while and I think I'm sort of giving up and coming here to ask now. I have a cloud code function that first lets me get a list of categories. Every category has multiple products. This one-to-many relationship is carried out using pointers, where every product points to the category it belongs to. However I'm failing to retrieve any products.

This my code,

```
Parse.Cloud.define("GetCategories", function(request, response) {
    var _ = require('underscore.js')
    var MSTCATEGORY_CLASS = "MSTCategory";
    var MSTPRODUCT_CLASS = "MSTProduct";
    var CATEGORY_TAG = "Category";
    var SHOP_TAG = "Shop";
    var VIEWS_TAG = "Views";

    var CAT_LIMIT = 10;
    var PROD_LIMIT = 5;

    var productList = [];
    var CatAndProd = [];

    var MSTCategory = Parse.Object.extend(MSTCATEGORY_CLASS);
    var query = new Parse.Query(MSTCategory);
    query.limit(CAT_LIMIT);

    query.find().then(function(results) {
        var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
        _.each(results, function(result) {
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                var MSTProduct = Parse.Object.extend(MSTPRODUCT_CLASS);
                var ProdQuery = new Parse.Query(MSTProduct);
                ProdQuery.equalTo(CATEGORY_TAG, result);
                ProdQuery.include(CATEGORY_TAG);
                ProdQuery.include(SHOP_TAG);
                ProdQuery.descending(VIEWS_TAG);
                ProdQuery.limit(PROD_LIMIT);

                var category = result;
                ProdQuery.find().then(function(ProdResults){
                    ProdResults.forEach(function(product) {
                        productList.push(product);
                    });

                    var singleItem = {
                        "category" : category,
                        "products" : productList
                    };
                    CatAndProd.push(singleItem);
                    return Parse.Promise.as("Hello!");
                });
            });
        });
        return promise;
    }).then(function(hello) {
        var jsonObject = {
            "categoryAndProducts": CatAndProd
        };
        response.success(jsonObject);
    });
});
```

What I am trying to do is after getting the category, I'd fetch products in it, add them to a jsonObject. And once I'm done with all categories. I'll create an array to carry all those json objects and send it as response. This is really basic, I'm pretty sure it's become my logic is incorrect. I'm new to Javascript and Parse.

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors:

- in your `_.each`, you are overwriting the same promise object in each loop
- you can return directly your `singleItem` via the promise resolving, not need for an extra array
- you're using a global `productList` array so the last category will have ALL products.

Try like this, I put few comments in the code:

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    // an array to store all our promises
    var promises = [];

    results.forEach(function(result) {
        // one promise for each result
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();

        var MSTProduct = Parse.Object.extend(MSTPRODUCT_CLASS);
        var ProdQuery = new Parse.Query(MSTProduct);
        ProdQuery.equalTo(CATEGORY_TAG, result);
        ProdQuery.include(CATEGORY_TAG);
        ProdQuery.include(SHOP_TAG);
        ProdQuery.descending(VIEWS_TAG);
        ProdQuery.limit(PROD_LIMIT);

        var category = result;
        ProdQuery.find().then(function(ProdResults) {
            // remove this
            // ProdResults.forEach(function(product) {
            //     productList.push(product);
            // });

            var singleItem = {
                "category" : category,
                "products" : ProdResults
            };

            // pass singleItem directly when resolving the promises 
            promise.resolve(singleItem);
        });

        promises.push(promise);
    });

    // return a promise resolving when ALL Promises are resolved
    return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
}).then(function(allProducts) {
    // allProducts is an array of singleItem
    var jsonObject = {
        "categoryAndProducts": allProducts
    };
    response.success(jsonObject);
});
```

Also, try to not mix `Array.forEach` and `_.each`, use one of them but not both at the same time.